# Websphere Liberty - How to fetch the keystore password from windows registry?

Tags: java, websphere, keystore, websphere-liberty, server.xml

I have an application running on Websphere Liberty and trying to explore ways to fetch keystore password from windows registry.

For instance - adding the keystore service object entry to the server.xml file. The keyStore element is called defaultKeyStore and contains the keystore password.

```
<keyStore id="samplePKCS12KeyStore" password="myPassword" location="MyKeyStoreFile.p12" type="PKCS12"  />
```

Is there a way to fetch password from the windows registry instead of having having it in the server.xml? Can there be a hook established from the java code ( application code) to server.xml for the ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to store passwords in non-filesystem storage.  Your best option is to [encrypt the server.xml passwords](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_pwd_encrypt.html) and store the decryption key in a separate directory.  Note that as that document describes, the server ultimately needs access to the actual passwords, so fundamentally, you can only ever obscure rather than prevent unauthorized access to passwords.

Comment: Also, can the password be blank for a keyStore ( KeyStore itself can be kep safe). For instance   -       <keyStore id="samplePKCS12KeyStore" password="" location="MyKeyStoreFile.p12" type="PKCS12"  />  . Password for .p12 file is  "". Is password mandatory

Comment: I have limited experience with key stores in general, but the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_ssl.html) for keyStore password says "Must be provided."